# Advantages of TFS 2012 Build Agents vs TFS 2010 Build Agents?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am testing the compatibility between TFS 2012 Source Control and TFS 2010 Build Agents, and I am glad to inform that they are compatible. I am wondering if there are any advantages to using TFS 2012 build agents. At this point, I have not found any information on advantages of using TFS 2012 build agents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2012 build agent support the new Unit Test Runner, Lab Management environment, .NET 4.5 building, improvements in CodedUI, capability to trigger tests on a 2012 test agent, 2012 version of Code Analysis, improvements to Code Coverage and many many other things.

The main reason to support 2010 build agents, is to allow you to upgrade TFS from 2010 to 2012 without having to big-bang upgrade all build agents. When the next version of TFS comes, it will support the 2012++ and the 2012 build agents. It will no longer support the 2010 build agent.